# Is it OK to define RowMapper class as spring bean?

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

On many tutorial/books about spring JDBC, `RowMapper` class usually represented as `private static final class` inside DAO and the instance is created in every single query.
Does `RowMapper` have to be used and instantiate in this way?

Is it ok if I define `RowMapper` class as spring bean using `@Component` annotation and `@Autowired` it to my dao class?

Which one is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does `RowMapper` have to be used and instantiate in this way

No, that's just a common usage pattern.

> Is it ok if I define `RowMapper` class as spring bean using `@Component` annotation and `@Autowired` it to my dao class?

Sure, that would work. Unless the `RowMapper` needs access to other Spring services, though, there's not much point.

> Which one is better?

Without seeing your code and getting a feel for your application, we can't really tell you if it's a good idea or not, only you can make that choice.

My personal preference would be to keep the `RowMapper` as a non-static inner class of your DAO class, and to insantiate it directly from the DAO.  If the `RowMapper` needs access to other Spring beans, then wire those intop the DAO, and access them from the `RowMapper` inner class.